# In Idris, how can I enforce ordering in a data type for a binary search tree

Tags: idris

I'm having problems to enforce the ordering in a binary search tree in Idris, and I'm not even sure I'm using the right approach.

Coming from Liquid Haskell, the idea behind the implementation is creating a simple binary tree and then refining the types in the initial structure (as it can be seen here https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-tutorial/Tutorial_12_Case_Study_AVL.html).

When trying to translate the same ordering restriction to Idris, things get a bit thorny.

Here's what I'm doing, first, I start with a simple definition of a binary tree, same as Haskell.

```
data Tree : (a: Type) -> Type where
  Leaf  : Tree a
  Node  : (key: a) -> (left: Tree a) -> (right: Tree a) -> Tree a
```

Having this in hand (and following up this question: [Encoding a binary search tree in data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078369/encoding-a-binary-search-tree-in-data-type/66085324#66085324)), I constructed another data type that should enforce the "search" part of the binary search tree, as follows:

```
minVal : Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a
minVal Leaf                      = Nothing
minVal (Node key Leaf _)         = Just key
minVal (Node key left right)     = minVal left

maxVal : Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a
maxVal Leaf                      = Nothing
maxVal (Node key _ Leaf)         = Just key
maxVal (Node key left right)     = maxVal right

lessTree : Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
lessTree x node = case minVal node of
                   Nothing => True
                   Just key  => x < key

moreTree : Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
moreTree x node = case maxVal node of
                   Nothing => True
                   Just key  => x >= key

IsLft : Ord a => (x: a) -> (left: Tree a) -> Type
IsLft x left = So (moreTree x left)

IsRgt : Ord a => (x: a) -> (right: Tree a) -> Type
IsRgt x right = So (lessTree x right)

data IsBST : (t : Tree a) -> Type where
  IsBSTLeaf : IsBST Leaf
  IsBSTNode : Ord a => (x: a) -> (IsBST left) -> (IsLft x left) -> (IsBST right) -> (IsRgt x right) -> (IsBST (Node x left right))

BSTree : Type -> Type
BSTree a = (t : (Tree a) ** (IsBST t))
```

Basically, the "proof" that a BST is a BST would be that the left tree is also a BST and should be in the left side (as in its root value is smaller than its parent), and the same idea for the right side.
This code compiles, but it doesn't work as expected, it can be seen in the implementation of an insert function, as below:

```
data Comp = LT | EQ | GT

comp : Ord a => a -> a -> Comp
comp x y = if x > y then GT else if x < y then LT else EQ

wrongInsert : Ord a => (x : a) -> BSTree a -> BSTree a
wrongInsert x (Leaf ** IsBSTLeaf) = 
  let isLftPrf = mkIsLft x Leaf
      isRgtPrf = mkIsRgt x Leaf
  in  ((Node x Leaf Leaf) ** (IsBSTNode x IsBSTLeaf isLftPrf IsBSTLeaf isRgtPrf))
wrongInsert x ((Node y left right) ** (IsBSTNode y lPrf isLftPrf rPrf isRgtPrf)) =
  case comp y x of
       LT => 
       let (lTree ** pl) = wrongInsert x (left ** lPrf)
           isLft         = mkIsLft y lTree
       in  ((Node y lTree right) ** (IsBSTNode y pl isLft rPrf isRgtPrf))
       GT => 
       let (rTree ** pr) = wrongInsert x (right ** rPrf)
           isRgt         = mkIsRgt y rTree
       in  ((Node y left rTree) ** (IsBSTNode y lPrf isLftPrf pr isRgt))
       EQ => ((Node y left right) ** (IsBSTNode y lPrf isLftPrf rPrf isRgtPrf))
```

In that case, the "LT" and "GT" parts are inverted, as in something greater than the root is being inserted in the left side, and vice-versa, so it shouldn't be possible to create such a tree, yet it works, which implies that Idris is accepting the creation of a "So False" (which I thought shouldn't be impossible, since there's only a constructor for True from what I've looked at).
From what I read on other sources, maybe using "So" is not the better idea here, but I fail to see other way to create a restriction in Idris as I have in Liquid Haskell, so that the data type itself prevents me from implementing a wrong insert function, as in the example above. Is that even possible, or if this approach is completely wrong, what would be the right way of implementing such a restriction?

Comment: I don't think Idris will be / can be expected to see the connection between the `comp` branches and the `moreTree` results. However, when you try to *use* `wrongInsert`, does that not give you unsolved metas?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But the problem here would be that even if I remove the `comp` part and use a simple `>` or `<` to compare the stuff, I'm still enforcing the ordering of the tree via the insert function and not via the data type.
The point here being, the `IsLft` and `IsRgt` should be the ones enforcing the ordering, but they aren't working as I expected